# Syntax explanation for "new" keyword for contracts in Solidity

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts

I am trying to understand the syntax of `C c = new C();`

I read the `new` keyword deploys, initializes state variables, runs the constructor, sets nonce to one, and returns address of new instance.

I read that a state variable `a` has a 0-ary public getter function `a()` that returns the value of `a`.

Questions:

1. What "is" the getter function of a contract?
2. Why does `new` act on the getter function?
3. In `C c = new C();` why do we need the first `C` to define the variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What "is" the getter function of a contract?*
>
> *Why does new act on the getter function?*

You can create a pointer to an already deployed contract by omitting the `new` keyword. Mind that the address is **not** a constructor param - it's an address of the external contract.

```
// points to a contract already deployed on address 0x123
C c = C(address(0x123));
```

> *In `C c = new C();` why do we need the first `C` to define the variable?*

Solidity is a strictly typed language. So the first `C` defines a variable type `C`.

Comment: Asked a follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71461912/18381563).