# Inferface vs contract type for new variable in solidity

Tags: interface, solidity, smartcontracts

Suppose a contract `C` inherits an interface `I`. What is the difference between `C c = new C()` and `I c = new C()`? In both cases `c` points to a newly deployed instance of `C`, no? (I'm looking [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/solidity-basics-of-interface/).)

More generally, what is the difference between `I c;` and `C c;`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the contract implements some of its methods extending the interface, you can invoke these (extended) methods as well with the `C` type variable.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8;

interface I {
    function foo() external;
}

contract C is I {
    function foo() override external {
        // implements the `foo()` function of the `I` interface
    }

    function otherFunction() external {
    }
}

contract Factory {
    function deploy() external {
        // the `I` type variable `i` can only invoke the `foo()` function
        I i = new C();
        i.foo();

        // the `C` type variable `c` can invoke the `otherFunction()` as well
        C c = new C();
        c.foo();
        c.otherFunction();
    }
}
```

If both the contract and the interface define the same set of methods (e.g. remove the `otherFunction()` from the example), then both snippets - `I i = new C();` and `C c = new C();` - effectively have the same functionality.